# Ionic tabs vanish after using back button

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have tabs in my ionic app, when i go to pages and back again to my tabs the tabs-bar will disappear.

**[Demo](https://i.ibb.co/n6J9hWC/Untitled-Project.gif)**

## Code

`tab1`

link sample to other pages

```
<ion-label routerDirection="forward" [routerLink]="['/tabs/', 'groups', group.id]">sample text</ion-label>
```

And then in my other page i have back button like:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar class="header-bg">
        <ion-buttons slot="start">
        <ion-back-button></ion-back-button> // back to tab1
        </ion-buttons>
        <ion-title [innerHTML]="messages?.name"></ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

**But** I also have this code in my page component which prevent tabs to be shown in that page.

```
ngOnInit() {
    // hide tab bar in current page
    const tabs = document.querySelectorAll('ion-tab-bar');
    Object.keys(tabs).map((key) => {
      tabs[key].style.display = 'none';
    });
}
```

> Note: code above only hides tab bars inside my second page and not tabs page, normally when i back to tabs they should be visible. `PS:` I'm not saying that this code cause the issue, I just thought it might be worth to mention that I have such code.

**Any idea why my tabs not showing when I back to tabs pages?**

Comment: Do you have any errors in the JS console ?

Comment: @Nicolas no but i will double check just to be sure.

Comment: @Nicolas no error at all.

Comment: Can you check if the display property is still set to `none` when you don't see them. If so, i'd say a quick fix would be to set it back to something like `block` or `flex`. Just like you are doing to hide them.

Comment: @Nicolas yes is still set to none

Comment: you have hidden your tabs with your code. that's why its not appearing again. Just remove the none property on ion will leave

Comment: @Luckyy in second page yes

Comment: @mafortis Then you could reuse your loop in the component where you want to display your tabs and then set them back to a display other than `none`.

Comment: @Nicolas so when my app is open (first time) is opening `tab1` if i add that code to use flex it's like double! (once showing by default and once i've forced it by my code) right?

Comment: @mafortis Well, you could check if their display is set to none, if so, you change the value to flex. But setting a display twice should not be a big deal, as long as it's the same value.

Comment: @Nicolas you're right I've managed to make it happen, thanks a lot.

Comment: @mafortis There is surely some more elegent way of fixing your problem, but i'm glad i could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## solved

I've bring back my tabs style with this code

```
ionViewDidLeave() {
    const tabs = document.querySelectorAll('ion-tab-bar');
    Object.keys(tabs).map((key) => {
      tabs[key].style.display = 'flex';
    });
}
```

> Code above restores my tabs default style when user is leaving my second page.

-Thanks to `Nicolas` suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Remove none from style before leaving the page:

using ngOnDestroy or ionViewWillLeave

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    // hide tab bar in current page
    const tabs = document.querySelectorAll('ion-tab-bar');
    Object.keys(tabs).map((key) => {
      tabs[key].style.display = 'block';
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks man i used `ionViewDidLeave` which is same as your `ngOnDestroy` but don't use `block`, block with transfer first tab to full width and cover other tabs. use `flex` instead.